# How to isolate asynchronous requests

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-volley, networkonmainthread

I am stuck on a problem, deriving from the following facts:

- Android Main thread **should not be blocked**
- I need to perform **dependent** network calls (for example a *login* request onSuccess of an *authentication* request)
- onSuccess of the *login* request I need to update the UI (like navigating from an Activity to another).

I could solve this issue this just by nesting the code in Volley directly in my Activity and having this pattern:

```
authenticationRequest() {
     onSuccess(): loginRequest() {
           onSuccess(): navigateTo(someActivity)
           onError(): // display some error
     }
     onError(): // display some error
}
```

And this could also be an exceptional case since it occurs just once in the application.
However, you can guess that there may be some other cases of request `B` getting triggered on response of `A`, but I could be interested in using only `A` and not `B` in some other scenarios.

That's the reason why I think it would be great to isolate methods independently and let me compose them only when necessary.

The problem is that the asynchronous nature of these functions doesn't let me avoid the dependency. Instead, it seems like dependency implies synchronous requests or duplicated nested code everywhere. I am never able to have in my Activity something like:

```
authenticationRequest()
// wait for the result without freezing main thread
loginRequest() 
// wait for the result without freezing main thread
navigateTo(someActivity)
```

The closest solution I was getting was a little verbose and a little dirty:
create **observable live data** and do `postValue(response)` where response is the value onSuccess or onError; consequently, in the Activity I had something like:

```
authenticationRequest()
authenticationResponse.observe(this, {
       loginRequest()
       loginResponse.observe(this, {
             navigateTo(someActivity)
       })
})
```

but this solution overcomplicates the management of observable data getting triggered twice when I go back and forward in some Activities.

Do you have any better suggestion?

*Edit Note*: the order of the functions execution **matters**.

Comment: Well, you just discovered what is the problem with asynchronous code. And honestly, in a very small scale so far, because it could get much worse. Relatively easy to implement solution is to use futures/promises instead of callbacks. They're much easier to chain. Proper solution on Android is to use coroutines and suspendable functions. Then you get synchronous code as in your example, but you don't block the main thread.

Comment: `I am never able to have in my Activity something like:` yes, that's the nature of async requests, they don't complete top down and there are ways of dealing with this. even if you make use of coroutines you'd still need a way of knowing what the result was in a manner you can relate to your UI.

Comment: Another solution is to make all your functions blocking, execute them in a background thread synchronously and jump to UI thread only when needed. But I would say this solution is worse than mentioned above.

Comment: you can make use of coroutines to execute service calls and then make use of something like live data to observe the result of that service call, which will then decouple your UI from the actual service call

Comment: @broot That would be fantastic: I don't know if you code also in Scala but it would be convenient to have a similar behavior of Future() construct.
Do you have any pointer for a parallel in Kotlin?

Comment: @a_local_nobody and with coroutines I can make the execution follow the exact order that I need?

Comment: In some way, it would be a solution to have an async block where inside requests are synchronous

Comment: i think, having a mentality of `can i execute this in the order i need` or `how can i do this synchronously` is a useless mindset to have :) you can use rxjava, coroutines, threads, doesn't really matter _what_ you use, but you need to know how to provide those changes in a way which makes sense. a typical approach people take is to do service call(s) and update a LiveData (or any other form of component which you can observe on) with the result of the calls. this means that your UI just has to know what to do once a certain state is reached, and _when_ that state happens is irrelevant

Comment: it's not irrelevant if that state is reachable through the composition of multiple requests. As a consequence, you can see that I am forced to nest the code.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I can see that UI must be updated only when result is available and for that I agree with you that a solution is to observe that value until request is completed.
But what about other chained network calls?

Let's put it in this way: if the result of a request depends on the outcome of another, can these two requests be handled in two asynchronous separate ways?

Comment: `if the result of a request depends on the outcome of another, can these two requests be handled in two asynchronous separate ways?` isn't this impossible ? if one depends on the other then surely they can't be handled separately, but yes, there are ways of dealing with this, you're not the first person to find this problem. apps make service calls and sometimes some of these calls need other data first. you have multiple tools available to help with this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unfocused. After reading both your question and comments you seem to have several concerns regarding synchronous/asynchronous execution. I won't answer all your concerns, but I can at least give you some insights on this topic.

1. In ideal world, the only reason to choose between synchronous and asynchronous is what we (the caller) currently need. If we need to execute `A`, `B` and `C` requests, where `B` uses data from `A` and `C` uses data from `B`, then we invoke them sequentially. If they are independent, we invoke them concurrently and join on them all.
2. Synchronous code is easier to develop and maintain and therefore it is generally preferable over async if we don't need parallel execution.
3. Historically, we were forced to use async code for strictly technical reasons. Such code have better performance and does not block critical threads like UI thread.
4. Because of 3. we often use async code. Still, we don't like it because of 2. We invented tools that help us work with async code in a more convenient way, for example futures/premises. They're far from ideal, but often they're better than callbacks.
5. Recently, we invented tools that have advantages of both synchronous and asynchronous code, placing us much closer to the ideal situation described in 1. These tools for JVM are mostly: Kotlin coroutines and Project Loom (not yet available), but there are also others, e.g.: Quasar. With coroutines and when keeping all long-running functions suspendable, we can code like this: `val a = requestA(); val b = requestB(a); requestC(b);` or: `launch { requestA() }; launch { requestB() }; launch { requestC() }` - whichever we need at the time. The performance is always as we code asynchronously.

Comment: Point 5 is exactly what I am looking for, but I have not been able to achieve that through Coroutines

Comment: @GiovanniLaganà It does not answer your question directly, but I just wrote an answer on similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966845/448875 . I should probably start writing a blog or something :-/ So the answer is: it really depends on what is the library you use for IO. Some libs support suspend functions natively. Other provide callback API and then you can convert it to suspend function. If library supports blocking IO only then we can use it with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` - it is far from perfect, but not that bad either.